# how to Json request convert to native object or list?

Tags: objective-c, json, native

```
{
"id": "1",
"result": [
{
"Name": "John",
"Statu": "Online"
},
{
"Name": "Alex",
"Statu": "Online"
},
{
"Name": "Diaz",
"Statu": "Offline"
}
]
}
```

How do i extract each "car" JSON object and put it into a native object? I tried several way but i can't do that.

```
    NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

       NSString *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue]; 

       NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[responseDict valueForKeyPath:@"result.Name"],[responseDict valueForKeyPath:@"result.Statu"],nil];
       NSLog(@"objects Array: %@",objects);



     **==> NSLOG gives:
                      (
                        (
                        "John",
                        "Alex",
                        "Diaz"
                        ),
                        (
                        "Online",
                        "Online",
                        "Offline"
                        )
                      )



    NSArray *resultsArray = [responseString JSONValue];

     for (NSDictionary *personDict in resultsArray) 
        {

       NSLog(@"ihaleAdi =: %@",[carDict valueForKey:@"result.ihaleAdi"]);

       NSLog(@"ihaleDurum =: %@",[carDict valueForKey:@"result.Statu"]);

       }
```

But ıt gıves an error tooç I want to just lıst them but ı cant do thatç can anybody help me please? thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Array to capture the responseString:

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSArray *array = [responseString JSONValue];
```

Then when you need an individual item from that array use a Dictionary:

```
// 0 is the index of the array you need
NSDictionary *itemDictionary = (NSDictionary *)[array objectAtIndex:0];
```

Given a JSON responseString that looks like this:

[{"UniqueID":111111,"DeviceName":"DeviceName1","Location":"Device1Loc","Description":"Device1Desc"},{"UniqueID":22222,"DeviceName":"DeviceName2","Location":"Device2Loc","Description":"Device2Desc"}]

You will wind up with an Array that looks like this:

```
myArray = (
        {
        Description = "Device1Desc";
        DeviceName = "DeviceName1";
        Location = "Device1Loc";
        UniqueID = 111111;
    },
        {
        Description = "Device2Desc";
        DeviceName = "DeviceName2";
        Location = "Device2Loc";
        UniqueID = 222222;
    }
)
```

And a Dictionary of index 0 that looks like this:

```
myDictionary = {
    Description = "Device1Desc";
    DeviceName = "DeviceName1";
    Location = "Device1Loc";
    UniqueID = 111111;
}
```

Sorry for any confusion and improperly instantiated object earlier.  I am still a relative newbie that learned something today.

Comment: The top line (NSString *responseString = [request responseString];) assumes you are using an ASIHttpRequest delegate method.  If you are instantiating the request object some other way, ignore that line.

Comment: The second line creates an array that is overwritten by the JSONValue. You've leaked it.

Comment: it gives an error something like : [__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b43300

Comment: That's because you're trying to access a dictionary with a method that is used to get objects out of an array.

Comment: Abizem yes but how can get these values to native object

Comment: @Abizem - You're right in that I instantiated and then overwrote it, but it isn't leaked.  I release it when I am done with it.  Also, I use that exact same method lots (in my tableView cell for indexPath method) and have no issues.  If the Array is a collection of NSDictionaries, then that method works fine.

Comment: BTW - A Dictionary is an object

Comment: @ElJay No you don't. `[responseString JSONValue]` returns a **completely different** object. not only that, but it is autoreleased. This overwrites the array that you alloc'd and init'd in the line above. Since you no longer have a pointer to that array, you can't release it, so it's leaked. Run it through the static analyser or Instruments if you don't believe me.

Comment: @Abizem, [embarrassed].  You're right it will leak that object.  I stand corrected :)

Comment: @ElJay No problems, then. Glad you took my comments in the spirit they were intended. :)

Comment: so what is wrong my responseString 
{
"id": "1",
"result": [
{
"Name": "John",
"Statu": "Online"
},
{
"Name": "Alex",
"Statu": "Online"
},
{
"Name": "Diaz",
"Statu": "Offline"
}
]
}

Comment: That would convert to an NSDictionary with one KV pair containing an NSArray of 3 NSDictionaries.  Plug both strings (mine and yours) into [this tool](http://www.jollydroll.com/tools/json) and you will see what I mean.